# Update an array table with ajax(just changed values)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, dynamic

I want to update the data changing only, with ajax,and I load the data every 5 seconds

I have two pages,the first contain the data(an array table) and the second displays the result as shown in the code. I want this page changes only changed values

For the code in the first page I load data from the server(xml file) and I store it in an array table.

Help me please.

thank you.

Comment: Your code will replace the HTML element with the data id with what's in gettable.php, we need to see your HTML in both file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating only new data is possible with `$.ajax`. But there is no any magic method to do that. You must keep track of items changed between requests on server and return only those in JSON. Than, in `success` calback - go through all received elements (for instance, that could be an array with item to update as a key and value as a new value for that item) and update them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "gettable.php",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#data").text(data); // this is assuming #data is a td or div like element
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This allows me to upload only new or changed data?

Comment: This allows you to pull data. Aka whatever gettable.php outputs will be thrown into the data variable in the success function.  If you want to pass data you can do that via the query string: gettable.php?somedata=anything. Or you can use jquery post: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/